# JavaScript - Convert a four-character array to an integer

Tags: javascript, arrays, integer, character

How can i convert a four-character array to an integer?

Comment: Where's the most significant digit? At `[0]` or at `[3]`? Also: what base?

Comment: Can you show the code you have written to do this so far?

Comment: Just to be sure: you're not secretly hoping for JavaScript characters to be 8-bit, are you?

Comment: Using which base? The answers you're getting assume binary hex, decimal ,etc.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to turn those characters into ASCII character codes and using the codes as byte values. This can be done using `charCodeAt`. For instance:

```
var str = "x7={";
var result = ( str.charCodeAt(0) << 24 )
           + ( str.charCodeAt(1) << 16 )
           + ( str.charCodeAt(2) << 8 )
           + ( str.charCodeAt(3) );
```

This returns 2016886139 as expected.

However, bear in mind that unlike C++, JavaScript will not necessarily use a one-byte, 256-character set. For instance, `'€'.charCodeAt(0)` returns 8364, well beyond the maximum of 256 that your equivalent C++ program would allow. As such, any character outside the 0-255 range will cause the above code to behave erraticaly.

Using Unicode, you can represent the above as "砷㵻" instead.

Comment: numbers are stored as 64bit Integers in Javascript. Using bitwise operators, they are converted into 32bit.

Comment: jAndy: I agree, and the above is identical whether run on 64-bit or 32-bit. My point is that having bytes with values larger than 255 would cause them to spill over in the byte above.

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = [5,2,4,0],
    foo = +arr.join('');

console.log(foo, typeof foo);
```

Comment: Doesn't the poster specifically say four characters, not numbers?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that depends on how you want to map the character values to the integer's bits.

One straight-forward solution would be:

```
var myArray = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
var myInt = (myArray[0].charCodeAt(0) << 24) | (myArray[1].charCodeAt(0) << 16) | (myArray[2].charCodeAt(0) << 8) | myArray[3].charCodeAt(0);
```

This produces the integer `0x01020304`. This uses integers in the input array, for characters the result might be different depending on the characters used.

Update: use `charCodeAt()` to convert characters to code points.

Comment: The characters would be converted to integers by `<<`, so any character outside `[0-9]` would be treated as zero.

Comment: I am trying to do something like this , but in your array don't you use numbers?
//That's a C++ code
 int toInt(const char* bytes) {
  return (int)(((unsigned char)bytes[3] << 24) |
      ((unsigned char)bytes[2] << 16) |
      ((unsigned char)bytes[1] << 8) |
      (unsigned char)bytes[0]);
 }

Answer (score 0):

```
var chArr = ['1','2','3','4'];
var num = parseInt( chArr.join(''), 10);
```

or

```
var num = parseInt( chArr.reverse().join(''), 10);
```

if depending on the order you array is filled..